# How can I change git history (git rebase -i) after I did a git push

Tags: git

How can I do a `git rebase -i` after I do a `git push`?
I read that I can't edit history after I do `git push`.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* edit history after a push, it's just not recommended. In fact, rebasing in general is not recommended.

`git push -f` will update the remote after a rewrite. If you have other people reading that source then doing a push -f after rewriting will mess up their repos.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are interested about:

```
man git-filter-branch
```

All necessary stuff is in there. There are also some examples. See also [`man git-rebase`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-rebase), [`man git-push`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-push). It's all explained there, just take your time to read it.